# chage measures (?) in lebesgue integration

Tags: statistics, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

When I read statistics papers, I often see
 $$\int g(x) dF_n(x) - \int g(x) dF(x) = TV([F_n(x)-F(x)]g(x)) + \int(F_n(x)-F(x))dg(x), $$
where $TV(\cdot)$ is total variation, $F_n(x)$ is an empirical distribution of $x$, $F(x)$ is a population distribution of $x$ and $g$ is a measurable function.

How does above equality holds? Also, how should I interpret $dg(x)$?

Comment: Can you give a reference (example)?

Comment: @d.k.o. https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177697495 at the end of page 2 ()

Comment: Your expression (which doesn't make sense) is different. (1) $g$ is not just a measurable function; it should be a function of bounded variation; (2) They consider the supremum of the absolute value of the LHS.

Comment: Regarding $d g(x)$ see [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration).

Comment: @d.k.o. thanks to your reference, I can see that the equality comes from simple integration by parts